# removing duplicates rows of a dataframe python

Tags: python

I need to remove duplicate rows from a dataset. Basically, I should perform

```
proc sort data=mydata noduprecs dupout=mydata_dup;run;
```

I need to remove duplicates as well as save those duplicate rows in a separate `dataframe`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your dataset is a pandas dataframe.

To remove the duplicated rows:

```
data = data.drop_duplicates()
```

To select all the duplicated rows:

```
dup = data.ix[data.duplicated(), :]
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A few examples from [Pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
> df = pd.DataFrame({

    'brand': ['Yum Yum', 'Yum Yum', 'Indomie', 'Indomie', 'Indomie'],

    'style': ['cup', 'cup', 'cup', 'pack', 'pack'],

    'rating': [4, 4, 3.5, 15, 5]

})

> df
    brand style  rating
0  Yum Yum   cup     4.0
1  Yum Yum   cup     4.0
2  Indomie   cup     3.5
3  Indomie  pack    15.0
4  Indomie  pack     5.0
```

By default, it removes duplicate rows based on all columns.

```
> df.drop_duplicates()
    brand style  rating
0  Yum Yum   cup     4.0
2  Indomie   cup     3.5
3  Indomie  pack    15.0
4  Indomie  pack     5.0
```

To remove duplicates on specific column(s), use subset.

```
> df.drop_duplicates(subset=['brand'])
    brand style  rating
0  Yum Yum   cup     4.0
2  Indomie   cup     3.5
```

To remove duplicates and keep last occurrences, use keep.

```
> df.drop_duplicates(subset=['brand', 'style'], keep='last')
    brand style  rating
1  Yum Yum   cup     4.0
2  Indomie   cup     3.5
4  Indomie  pack     5.0
```